# Node labels not appearing in Sankey from Python Plotly

Tags: plotly, axis-labels

Trying my first sankey flow diagram using Python Plotly. The sankey flow diagram appears perfectly with the right source and target. But I am unable to include the node labels. The labels are inside a dataframe. Without the labels for the various sources and targets the diagram is incomplete. Here are the codes that I used. My aim is to get a static diagram.

```
{link = dict(source = Service_df, target=Manufac_df, value=Revenue_df)}
{node = dict(label=Label_df, pad=50, thickness=5)}
{data = dict(type = 'sankey', hoverinfo = 'all', link = link, node=node)}
{fig = go.Figure(data)}
{fig.show() }
```

Later, I tried to hardcord the labels for the source and target. That also didn't work.

When I hover over the diagram, I get the message Source:Undefined Target:Undefined. At the same time, the incoming and outgoing flow count is seen while hovering at Source or Target.

I'm trying this out in Jupyter Notebook Python 3.8.5

The dataframes are as follows:

```
{MainData.info()}
```

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 31 entries, 0 to 30
Data columns (total 3 columns):

## Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype

---

0   Service       31 non-null     int64
1   Manufacturer  31 non-null     int64
2   Revenue       31 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2)

```
{LabelData.info()}
```

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 1 columns):

## Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype

---

0   Label   10 non-null     object
dtypes: object(1)

The image I get is over here. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QDc-qVyMYSTJNI0coNJf8Ehuq8tlL-mP?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add the dataframes to your question?

Comment: Hello Maximilian, here is the link to the .csv files which I used for the dataframe. One doubt - Should the size of labels, source, target and value be all the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your dataframes, I'd assume that your `Label_df` has a different shape/size than your dataframes in `link`.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# mock data, identical to the plotly documentation https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/
Label_df = pd.DataFrame(["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"])
Service_df = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3])
Manufac_df = pd.DataFrame([2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5])
Revenue_df = pd.DataFrame([8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2])

link = dict(source = Service_df[0], target=Manufac_df[0], value=Revenue_df[0])
# this works
node = dict(label=Label_df[0], pad=50, thickness=5)
data = dict(type='sankey', hoverinfo='all', link=link, node=node)
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()

# this gives Source:Undefined Target:Undefined
node = dict(label=list(Label_df[0]), pad=50, thickness=5)
data = dict(type='sankey', hoverinfo='all', link=link, node=node)
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Dataframe added to the question now.

Comment: I created one sankey flow diagram using google sheets addon for the same data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14xOyk8KJ-JGx9J2peOqQmxrEaEyUx_sRPWb8LaI8wbs/edit?usp=sharing